# Deleting in Binary Tree sulotion

Tags: c++, binary-tree

After a few questions and some nice answers and friendly helpers here. I got the sulotion to my porblem with the deleting in the binary tree, i got suggested that, i can not just delet the largest number in the tree cause its may not the last or it has childrens 1 ,2 or none, so i made the code down below, i used a lot commenting hope that can help you people help me. What i actually dont know now, is how do i call this `RemoveLargest()` function in my public and then later in main, even though i dont know if the code will run properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib> 

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class BinaryTree
{
struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* lChildptr;
        Node* rChildptr;

        Node(T dataNew)
        {
            data = dataNew;
            lChildptr = NULL;
            rChildptr = NULL;
        }
    };
private:
    Node* root; 

        void Insert(T newData, Node* &theRoot) //Insert elements into the tree start.
        {
            if(theRoot == NULL) 
            {
                theRoot = new Node(newData);
                return;
            }
            if(newData < theRoot->data)  
                Insert(newData, theRoot->lChildptr);
            else
                Insert(newData, theRoot->rChildptr);
        }                               //end.

        void PrintTree(Node* theRoot) //print me the tree /start
        {
            if(theRoot != NULL)
            {
                PrintTree(theRoot->lChildptr);
                cout<< theRoot->data<<" \n";
                PrintTree(theRoot->rChildptr);
            }
        }                           //end.

        T Largest( Node* theRoot) // show me largest number /start.
            {
        if ( root == NULL )
            {
                 cout<<"There is no tree";
                 return -1;
            }
            if (theRoot->rChildptr != NULL)
            {
                 return Largest(theRoot->rChildptr);
            }
            T value = theRoot->data;
            return value;

        }                   //end.
        void RemoveLargest(Node* theRoot)  //remove the largest priority number from tree /start.
        {
            Node* current;  //the current tree?
            Node* parent;   //the parent of the current node?
            current=theRoot;

                // 3 cases :
                // 1. We're removing a leaf node
                // 2. We're removing a node with a single child
                // 3. we're removing a node with 2 children
            //Node with single child.
            if((current->lChildptr == NULL && current->rChildptr != NULL)||(current->lChildptr != NULL && current->rChildptr == NULL))
            {
                if(current->lChildptr == NULL && current->rChildptr != NULL)
                {
                    if(parent->lChildptr==current)
                    {
                        parent->lChildptr = current->rChildptr;
                        delete current;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parent->rChildptr = current->rChildptr;
                        delete current;
                    }
                }
                else //left child ok, no right child
                {
                    if(parent->lChildptr==current)
                    {
                        parent->lChildptr = current->lChildptr;
                        delete current;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parent->rChildptr = current->lChildptr;
                        delete current;
                    }
                }
            return;
            }
            //We found a leaf(a node with not a single child)
            if(current->lChildptr == NULL && current->rChildptr == NULL)
            {
                if (parent->lChildptr == current)
                    parent->lChildptr = NULL;
                else
                    parent->rChildptr = NULL;
                delete current;
                return;
            }
            //Node with 2 children
            // replace node with smallest value in right subtree
            if (current->lChildptr != NULL && current->rChildptr != NULL)
            {
                Node* checkr;
                checkr = current->rChildptr;
                if((checkr->lChildptr == NULL)&&(checkr->rChildptr == NULL))
                {
                    current=checkr;
                    delete checkr;
                    current->rChildptr = NULL;
                }
                else //right child has children
                {
                //if the node's right child has a left child
                //Move all the way down left to locate smallest element
                    if ((current->rChildptr)->lChildptr != NULL)
                    {
                    Node* lcurr;
                    Node* lcurrp;
                    lcurrp = current->rChildptr;
                    lcurr = (current->rChildptr)->lChildptr;
                    while(lcurr->lChildptr != NULL)
                        {
                            lcurrp = lcurr;
                            lcurr = lcurr->lChildptr;
                        }
                    current->data = lcurr->data;
                    delete lcurr;
                    lcurrp->lChildptr = NULL;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        Node* temp;
                        temp = current->rChildptr;
                        current->data = temp ->data;
                        current->rChildptr = temp->rChildptr;
                        delete temp;
                    }

                }
                return;
            }

        };

    public:
        BinaryTree()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }

        void AddItem(T newData)
        {
            Insert(newData, root);
        }

        void PrintTree()
        {
            PrintTree(root);
        }
        T Largest()
        {
            return Largest(root);
        }
        void RemoveLargest()
        {
            RemoveLargest();
        }

    };

    int main()
    {
        BinaryTree<int> *myBT = new BinaryTree<int>();
        myBT->AddItem(5);
        myBT->AddItem(1);
        myBT->AddItem(4);
        myBT->AddItem(2);
        myBT->AddItem(3);

            //for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)           //randommal tolti fel/fill with random
                //myBT->AddItem(rand() % 100);
        cout << "BinaryTree:" << endl;              //kilistazaa a fat/ list my tree
        myBT->PrintTree();
        cout << "Largest element: " << myBT->Largest() << endl;  //visszaadja a legnagyobb elemet/shows the largest number
        myBT->RemoveLargest();  //suposed to delet the largest number
        myBT->PrintTree(); //shows list again
  }
```

edited the code, now its running, its creating the tree, shows the largest, but after i call my remove function still crashing... =/

Comment: This is very complicated way of writing deleteLargest. Try to draw a diagram and understand what is it that you are supposed to do to delete the largest element. You should not have this many different cases.

Comment: im pretty sure , in the node with 1 and none child, the 2 child thing isnt 100%, for that start it would, be great if could call the function in my main, so i can start fix it.

Comment: make removeLargest public. So you may place a "public:" right after " Node* root; " line.

Comment: Also, your public interface better not refer to the "Node" structure. deleteLargest can be parameter free (remove root parameter you already know it.

Comment: 'void RemoveLargest()
       {
          RemoveLargest();
        }' so i just do this in the public? and then call it in the main like the other functions?

Comment: yes exactly, just like other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said before, I think you're making things overly complicated. You have to think of what it means that your node is the largest one, in the context of a binary search tree and the relationship between the keys in its nodes.

If a node is the largest one in the tree it cannot possibly have a right child pointer, because the right child would have to have a larger key. And then, if you know that it has at most a left child, you just replace your node with its possibly null left child, and you're done.

```
T ExtractLargest(Node*& n){

    if (!n)
        return -1;

    if (n->rChildptr)
        return ExtractLargest(n->rChildptr);

    T result = n->data;

    Node *d = n;
    n = n->lChildptr;
    delete d;

    return result;

}
```

Comment: I was over thinking it, totally complicated a simple thing, i asked to much got to many different answers(must not be wrong answers, all good in theyr own way but not the good for me) rather then just stick to your first suggestion, and think that to the end. I understand the whole thing now, and while reading thought the other answers i learned a lot, about Binary Trees, Templates and Pointers. I started master studies you know, and in my previous school we didnt had a really good teacher, and i didnt liked c++, and now i was droped in the middle! Now i start to like it, and will learn it

Comment: from the start, thank you again, and everyone who answered my questions.

Comment: I'm glad that you like it. It's a great language, even though overwhelming at times. Good luck with C++ and your studies!